# How can i check network connection on qml?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, nokia, qml

I want to check if there is network connection when my app start under splash screen.Splash doesnt important, important point is how can i check network connection in qml? Solution can be with qml, javascript, c++ etc.

Comment: i have solved it, QNetworkConfigurationManager::isOnline () solves problem. Link is
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html#isOnline 
and if there will be problem about library, it's solution is in here,
http://www.known-issues.net/qt/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#comment-210

Comment: QNetworkConfigurationManager::isOnline () returns false on Symbian when connected to a valid Wifi.

Comment: QNetworkConfigurationManager::isOnline () return true in plane mode in windows 10 (just tested on it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NetworkInfo QML element from the QtMobility.systeminfo 1.1 module.
See: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/qml-networkinfo.html for more information.